# Cant get value to insert DB PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im having trouble trying to insert a value into my database, 'randomkey' is inserting as 0...

on one page I have...

```
  if($usersClass->register($_POST['produgg_username'], md5($_POST['produgg_password']), $_POST['produgg_email'], $randomkey))
```

and the page which does the insert...

```
public function register($username, $password, $email)
    {
    $rs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$this->usersTable` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `randomkey` ) 
                    VALUES 
                    ('".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."',
                    '".$randomkey."'
                    )");

    if($rs) {
        return mysql_insert_id();
    }else{
        return false;
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to include it in the accepted paramters:

```
public function register($username, $password, $email)
```

Should be:

```
public function register($username, $password, $email, $randomkey)
```

Comment: Couldnt see the forest for the trees! Thankyou!

Comment: @Drewdin - shoot me a msg next time, and I'll hold off until you answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function register($username, $password, $email, $randomkey)
    {
    $rs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$this->usersTable` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `randomkey` ) 
                    VALUES 
                    ('".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."',
                    '".$randomkey."'
                    )");

    if($rs) {
        return mysql_insert_id();
    }else{
        return false;
    }       

}
```